# Race to Atlantis

Tags: cipher, visual

Not good.

It appears that dastardly Dr. Dawkins, the gentleman thief (and, incidentally, my life-long rival,) has actually succeeded in discovering the location of Atlantis.

I must find out where he's gone and stop him, before he plunders the site for his own personal gain!

Searching his office, I've found the notes he left behind:

[image: gate]

[image: nice woods]

[image: key]

[image: glyphs]

[image: numbers]

[image: dark woods]

Comment: I think I have the altitude figured out, but not the latitude yet... I feel like this is one of the puzzles that will bug me forever because I got so "close" but never solved it :P Very nice pictures, btw!

Comment: Do the vertical lines offer a key to deciphering the K2 text?

Comment: @MadPhysicist no...

Comment: Offering this as a suggestion to the other solvers: it may be important that the trees have leaves in one image but not in the other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've decrypted the pictures of the trees into what are probably coordinates, using the center picture as a map,

> it seems to be a base 10 system, with a base 5 semibase, causing the background trees.

The coordinates I get are

> 35.992862, 19.264688 which puts us a ways off the coast of Greece, which seems like as plausible a location for Atlantis as any.

The 'Keys' I imagine are additional pieces of information that need to come together to actually gain entrance.

> The first one looks a lot like Pi, and the second seems to be translatable to the English Language alphabet. "W Y V T Q J W B E E V J Z B F M P N F V T M X G S J O C L S B Z H X K O L W U N Y R R P" 
>  or, as pointed out in the comments, XZWURKXCFFWKACGNQOGWUNYHTKPDMTCAIYLPMXVOZSSQ

I've tried a few ciphers on the second set, but haven't found anything worth mentioning yet. It's only one symbol longer than a spaceless version of the words on the gate, but I haven't been able to make anything come of that either.

Although... there should be a connection between keys, trees, and pi.

> I see it! A Key Lime Pie! Bring one to the coordinates in question, feed it to whoever you find there to look the other direction, and break in with a sledgehammer!

Comment: Very close... You'll want to re-check all your digits, though :)

Comment: I think the numbers are the *indexes*, not the positions. I.e. `XZWURKXCFFWKACGNQOGWUNYHTKPDMTCAIYLPMXVOZSST`

Comment: @LukasRotter, when I put the nubers into excel, and use CHAR on them I get the last character to be `Q`

Comment: You've basically got the answer; the coordinates are correct.Well done! :) The hidden message just gives a clue to the trees' meaning.

Comment: Oh, drats. I've made an error somewhere with k2. I ran some python scripts to construct it, but it looks like there's a bug somewhere. It might not be solvable now :(

Comment: @YehudaShapira. Is it something you can fix?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, I need to find and re-run the scripts (they're on another computer...)

Answer (score 4):

### Partial Answer

The two keys stand for

> longitude and latitude

The first picture of trees is most likely

> The first key (longitude), also considering that the picture of "one key" might hint to that.

The picture with the cryptic symbols stands for

> A map, with which we can decrypt the messages

The K<sub>2</sub> most likely stands for

> something doing with the second key, the latitude (K = "Key", <sub>2</sub>="two"). I didn't figure out what this note is about, yet.

The second pictures of trees is

> The encrypted latitude

---

How to decrypt (at least the first line of trees):

> Convert the trees to the corresponding numbers on the map-note, i.e. map it to whatever symbol the tree looks alike. Chopped trees stand for a dot.

---

So the best guess I have is at this point:

> Here (30.774394,-19.419133)
> [image]
> **This is most likely incorrect**, since it doesn't take the K<sub>2</sub> note into consideration. I'm pretty confident about the longitude, since it would match the longitude given [here (second picture)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location_hypotheses_of_Atlantis), but the latitude seems a bit too high, which is surely because I couldn't decrypt the K<sub>2</sub> note (I also sneakily put a minus in front of the latitue).

Comment: Nice! Indeed, close. Actually, the keys are *not* the coordinates, but more information regarding them. There is also a nasty trickiness to this puzzle, but I'll wait before adding a hint regarding it.

Comment: The teeth of the key look suspiciously like a pi, so there may be some calculation or digit-wise operation involved. Could the numbers in the K2 image refer to the digits of pi at this position?

Comment: @MOehm Nice observation! I didn't even pay attention to that!

Comment: altitude == longitude?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, sorry. I didn't check if the translation (english is obviously not my first language) I had in mind was correct.

Comment: No worries. Like you said, it was totally apparent what you meant from context. I just wanted to check.